# Why svg embeded in javascript not working

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, reactjs, svg

Some reason i need use a react project in Rails html like this:

```html
<html>
  ...
  <script src="<react_project_bundle_file>.js"></script>
</html>
```

Because a lot of SVG images are used by icon in this react project, i'm tried refactor with `svg-sprite-loader` & `svgo-loader`. It's working very well when visit this page **first visit**, but **the second time** visited the page, none of these SvgIcon appear.

```
// svg-icon.jsx
import '../icons';

const SvgIcon = props => (
    <svg>
        <use xlinkHref={`#icon--${props.icon}`} />
    </svg>
);
```

```js
// icons/index.js

const requireAll = requireContext => requireContext.keys().forEach(requireContext);
// `icons/svg` is a subdirectory to store all SVG files
const req = require.context('./svg', false, /\.svg$/);
requireAll(req);
```

And svg inline in the bundle js file:

```js
"use strict";
...

var symbol = new _node_modules_svg_baker_runtime_browser_symbol_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default.a({
  "id": "icon--file-upload",
  "use": "icon--file-upload-usage",
  "viewBox": "0 0 20 20",
  "content": "<symbol xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\" viewBox=\"0 0 20 20\" id=\"icon--file-upload\"><path d=\"M5.917 6.886L9.64 3.165a.54.54 0 01.777 0l3.721 3.721c.355.355.096.94-.395.94h-1.854L10.784 12.2a.798.798 0 01-.968.573.78.78 0 01-.586-.573L8.126 7.825H6.313c-.491 0-.75-.584-.396-.939zM17 11.602v2.249A3.147 3.147 0 0113.865 17H6.149A3.15 3.15 0 013 13.851v-2.25c0-.572.463-1.022 1.022-1.022.56 0 1.023.45 1.023 1.023v2.249c0 .6.49 1.104 1.104 1.104h7.716c.6 0 1.09-.504 1.09-1.104v-2.25c0-.572.464-1.022 1.023-1.022.572 0 1.022.45 1.022 1.023z\" fill=\"#FFF\" fill-rule=\"evenodd\" /></symbol>"
});

...
```

#### HTML element debug

- First visit

  ```html
  <svg>
    <use xlink:href="#icon--upload">
      #shadow-root(closed)
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" ...>
        <path ...>
      </svg>
    </use>
  </svg>
  ```
- Second visit:

  ```html
  <svg>
    <use xlink:href="#icon--upload">
      #shadow-root(closed)
      !!! not anything !!!
    </use>
  </svg>
  ```

**What's the problem here? Why is it correct the first time and not the second time?**

Comment: Is it possible to Turbolinks cached ？

Comment: This shouldn't happen generally. Have you got a [CodeSandbox.io](https://react.new/) code we can see?

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman https://codesandbox.io/s/svgicon4stackoverflow-e1qsu

Comment: Maybe I've found the answer: **svg sprite not included**

Answer (score 0):

**Svg sprite not include!**

```js
fetch('svg-sprite.svg')
  .then(res => res.text())
  .then(data => {
    document.getElementById('svg-sprite').innerHTML = data;
  });
```

UPDATE:

**`svg-sprite.svg` not found!** worked by added **path** to `` <use xlinkHref={`static/svg-sprite.svg#icon--${icon}`} /> `` in the `<svg></svg>`

Comment: Awesome... Maybe it's loading it in a different way. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: That suggests you have a namespace issue. Your "fix" is just wallpaper over that.

Comment: @RobertLongson fixed it! https://stackoverflow.com/a/53485292/9197815 and https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/issues/2246#issuecomment-767603447 thx!